# Facebook like button on jQuery Mobile "hidden" page

Tags: jquery, facebook, cordova

I've tried searching for a solution on this for a while and have not yet been successful.

I'm running a cordova/phonegap app in jQuery mobile and the entire site resides in a single .html file

Each page is separated using the container:

```
<div data-role="page"   ... etc
```

I've been trying to use the following Facebook link to generate the like box:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

What is happening is that the box is physically not rendering on the page at all.

I've found a bunch of suggestions to do with not initialising the facebook markup until the page is "created"/ brought into view. Nothing so far has worked.. I'm hoping someone else out there is familiar with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i eventually found the answer on this page:

https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md

I'm not using that particular facebook plugin but it was really insightful. For anyone else facing similar issues, you cannot use the facebook likebox generator (js/html) inside a native app.

Check the link for more info :-)